# DynamoDB and Nodejs using FilterExpression and getting error message of ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Can someone please let me know why my variables isn't getting passed through?

It looks like that my `start` and `end` variables are not being passed through into my `params`.

Getting the error message of:

```
Unable to scan the table. Error JSON: { ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: NaN for key :queryDateEnd
```

If I replace the variables with raw UNIX timestamps, it works well.

```
  moment.tz.setDefault("Pacific/Auckland");
  var daysAgo = event.daysAgo;
  var currentDate = moment(new Date()).startOf("day");
  var start = moment(currentDate).subtract(7,'d').startOf("day");
  var end = moment(currentDate).subtract(6,'d').startOf("day");
  console.log("queryDateStart: "+start)
  console.log("queryDateEnd: "+end)
  var params = {
    TableName: "addToCart",
    ProjectionExpression: "#timestamp, newExisting",
    FilterExpression: "#timestamp between :start and :end",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#timestamp": "ctimestamp"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":queryDateStart": start,
      ":queryDateEnd": end
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to set the date to UNIX timestamp and then parseInt it.